# Error in finding urls from the website using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0'}
url = "https://ascscotties.com"
reqs = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile("roster"))
for link in links:
  print(link.get("href"))
```

The output:

```
https://ascscotties.com/roster.aspx?path=wbball
https://ascscotties.com/roster.aspx?path=wcross
https://ascscotties.com/roster.aspx?path=wsoc
https://ascscotties.com/roster.aspx?path=softball
https://ascscotties.com/roster.aspx?path=wten
https://ascscotties.com/roster.aspx?path=wvball
```

The code does not work for this https://owlsports.com/ both the website under sidearm platform. Also the landing page of https://owlsports.com/ does not have any of the roster links.

Comment: Could you clarify the issue please - If there are no links that contains *roster* in `href` you wont get one. What do you expect to get, what is your goal?

Comment: But I can find it in dropdown https://owlsports.com/sports/mens-basketball/roster

Comment: Okay, you can see it if you browse or inspect via dev tools, but not in your response / soup. Issue here content is served dynamically and renderd by the browser, a beahvior you could simulate with selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Would deleting the `href` parameter from your `find_all` query be impossible?
If getting all the urls from a website is your requirement, the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#:%7E:text=One%20common%20task%20is%20extracting%20all%20the%20URLs%20found%20within%20a%20page%E2%80%99s%20%3Ca%3E%20tags) shows just a simple

```py
links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    print(link.get("href"))
```

would do.

Please let me know how your case is different, so we can solve this together. Thank you.